# How do I turn on the showPhysics property in swift?

Tags: swift, skview

This is my code:

```
let skView = self.view as! SKView
skView.showsPhysics = true
```

However I keep getting an error saying:

> Downcast from SKView? to SKView only uwraps optionals; did you mean to use !?

It may be an easy fix but I am new to swift and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you have example code? [How to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It is part of the SKView,  make sure you are not loading any other views, and you are not using your simulator scaled down,  they are tiny little lines that wrap around a body, they may be there, you just can't see them.